# Camunda admin servlet context menu change

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

Camunda by default register under context path '/lib','/app' and '/api' (e.g. camunda cockpit). Problem here is that I need change these to something like '/camunda/*'.

Any idea where to change it? From the source code it rather seems to be hardcoded.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot you can influence the context path via *application.properties/application.yaml* using:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /camunda
```